# Topological implications of curvature singularities

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics

In popular articles on astronomy/physics, singularities are typically described as "holes or rips in the fabric of space".

Now algebraic topology has a lot of methods for detecting "holes of various dimensions" in a manifold. However, singularities in general relativity and differential geometry are typically described in terms of geodesic incompleteness which $\it intuitively $ suggests "holes or rips in the manifold".

> **Question.** Is this intuitive idea "mathematically detectable" - as in, does the existence/formation of a curvature singularity on a
> manifold alter its topology somehow? Or is it purely a "problem with
> the metric structure" which can't be detected topologically?

Comment: Lorentz manifolds have completions, so there is a rich framework to talk about the topological structure of the singularities.  Your first question appears a little ill-defined.  What do you mean by "alter" when dealing with space-time?  One has to be careful with the use of temporal language when talking about such objects.  So when you say "alter" what "change" are you making this in reference to?

Comment: Okay I'll try to explain my intuition here. So imagine those typical pictures of a rubber sheet with a dent in the middle to show "space curving due to the presence of a star". So what I'd like to say is "The rubber sheet is currently homeomorphic to R^2 but if the star collapses to a singularity then the sheet gets punctured and isn't simply connected anymore". What I'm asking is whether this description is mathematically accurate. Or is it the case that, mathematically speaking, there is no topological change and the singularity is just a blow-up of the metric ?

Comment: To make a comparison like that, the traditional way would be to talk about a spacetime where outside of a compact set it was essentially flat.   So provided there's no mass inside the compact region, you would have the expected flat spacetime as a comparable.  Not certain if that would suffice for your purposes.